# why my streaming api code does not echo anything in php (twitter app)?

Tags: php, streaming, twitter

I am trying to use the Streaming API from php, I use the code from Matt Harris [Streaming code](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/examples/streaming.php) but when I run the code with exec function nevers display a single word neither an error, how can I see the result of the exec function or what am I doing  wrong?

This is my code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Very basic streaming API example. In production you would store the
 * received tweets in a queue or database for later processing.
 *
 * Instructions:
 * 1) If you don't have one already, create a Twitter application on
 *      https://dev.twitter.com/apps
 * 2) From the application details page copy the consumer key and consumer
 *      secret into the place in this code marked with (YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
 *      and YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET)
 * 3) From the application details page copy the access token and access token
 *      secret into the place in this code marked with (A_USER_TOKEN
 *      and A_USER_SECRET)
 * 4) In a terminal or server type:
 *      php /path/to/here/streaming.php
 * 5) To stop the Streaming API either press CTRL-C or, in the folder the
 *      script is running from type:
 *      touch STOP
 *
 * @author themattharris
 */

function my_streaming_callback($data, $length, $metrics) {
  echo $data .PHP_EOL;
  return file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/STOP');
}

require 'tmhOAuth.php';
require 'tmhUtilities.php';
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => 'Y1qoRrUSevAnfpzPJiVpQ',
  'consumer_secret' => 'usZvJYGl1y5IRmImyNSVRGyOajMzsBMubzZND7Uh4',
  'user_token'      => '435894914-UHEEk87wPsiYI4tjSOxYiVvcKZdYon5qSxI376nN',
  'user_secret'     => '1MDdrNBaMZLStfHmngmEjaW6Lkfy5cNR9ySXiqaGw',
));

$method = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json';

// show Tweets which contan the word twitter OR have been geo-tagged within
// the bounding box -122.41,37.77,-122.40,37.78 OR are by themattharris

$params = array(
  'track'     => 'soyprole',
  // Around Twitter HQ. First param is the SW corner of the bounding box
  'locations' => '-122.41,37.77,-122.40,37.78',
  'follow'    => '777925' // themattharris
    );

$tmhOAuth->streaming_request('POST', $method, $params, 'my_streaming_callback');



// output any response we get back AFTER the Stream has stopped -- or it errors
tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth);
```

and the code that runs the script:

```
<?php


exec("C:\wamp\www\appTwitterNuevo3\script.php");

?>
```

Comment: In your php.in file, do you have anything like disable_functions=exec...?

Comment: @cillosis no I do not have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec("C:\wamp\www\appTwitterNuevo3\script.php");
```

That's not how you execute a PHP file. Also, you have invalid `\` (backslashes) there.

You may want to try either of these :

```
include("C:\\wamp\\www\\appTwitterNuevo3\\script.php");
```

or

```
system("C:\\wamp\\php\\php.exe C:\\wamp\\www\\appTwitterNuevo3\\script.php");
```

Comment: thanks for answering , I try with those but It is the same result that I have I think It is with the streaming code